# Set Up Xcode In Terminal

Tags: terminal

I was wondering how I could import a Xcode project into terminal on Mac. Right now the terminal just says My name and Macbook Pro. How could I get the terminal default line to say My Xcode project name so I can install the Cocoa Pods.

Sorry if this is a confusing question, I am new to Xcode.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, for installing Cocoa Pods you just need to navigate to the project, not import anything. Navigate by typing `cd` and then the folder's name you want to get in. Like this: `cd Desktop/XcodeProjects/MyProject`.

Comment: Ok, Thank You. @LinusG.

Comment: When I input this code it says, No Such File In Directory. @LinusG.

Comment: That was just sample code to show you how it works. You need to plug in your on path to the project directory.

Comment: No, I know I made a new folder and inputed the project in but still nothing showed up. @LinusG.

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen anyway?

Comment: Sorry, but I am just following this tutorial that shows his Xcode Project in the terminal and he is installing all of the pods, but when I implement the same code it comes up with nothing. @LinusG.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: No, there is no error message.

Comment: Ok, so it does open the directory? What happens when you hit `ls`? (LS) Does it list the project file?

Comment: Yes, it lists the project file when you hit ls. @LinusG.

Comment: @LinusG. Are You Still There?

Comment: Ok so you seem to be on track so far. What tutorial are you following?

Comment: The  Building An In-App Message Center With Slack tutorial. It is a youtube video. @LinusG.